# AppIcon not being shown

Tags: ios, xcode

May app has two storyboards, where the default Main.storyboard is used for iPad, and another one named iPhone.storyboard is used for iPhone build. The storyboard to be used by the app is chosen in AppDelegate, in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions after detecting which device is running the app.

For me, this two storyboard approach is very much simpler than working with adaptive layout, because of my app characteristics. But there is one side effect I couldn't overcome until now: when the app is installed on iPhone, the app icon is not being shown, even though I have the icon images for iPhone in Assets.xcassets. On iPad the icon is being shown correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Check in your target Build phases if your assets or the iPhone icon is included in the Copy Bundle Resources list

Comment: FYI - using two different storyboards for iPhones and iPads is a really bad idea.  You still need to deal with adaptive layout since your iPhone storyboard needs to work with several different iPhone screen sizes and your iPad storyboard needs to work with 2 major screen sizes plus several other sizes if you wish to support iPad multitasking. You really should rethink your approach.

Comment: @Leo Dabus: yes, my Assets.xcassets is included in the Copy Bundle Resources list. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @maddy: I have been working hard at improving my adaptive layout knowledge. In some extent, I have used it to deal with the different sizes of iPhones and iPads on their respective storyboards. But in the case of this particular app, it seems that coping with adaptive layout for both iPhones and iPads seems to take more effort than doing the whole swift programming. But I really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered that I was using a wrong sized image for the icon. I had two separate projects for iPhone and iPad before. Funny that I made the same mistake then, but the iPhone app icon was shown anyway. I also made this mistake for iPad in this new joint project, but, as I mentioned before, I had no problem with the iPad icon. Sorry for bothering with this silly question.